# SSRS report parameter visibility

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, reportparameter

I have a SSRS report which takes 8 parameters.  On the report server when I am testing, I can see 8 fields show up along with a 'View Report' button.

Now, I am trying to use ReportViewer control in ASP.NET to show this same SSRS report with parameters.  In the ReportViewer control I can see the same 8 fields with 'View Report' button.  But, in ASP.NET application I only want to show 2 parameter fields to the user.  I want to hide the other 6 parameters from the end-user.

I was thinking about fetching rdl file as XML and look into the ReportParameters section and hide or show parameters based on a config file.  Is there any better way?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a linked report on your report server, and hide the 6 parameters you want to hide in the linked report.   Then point the ReportViewer to the linked report.